# Deploying modules in a web application

Tags: java, deployment, web-applications, tomcat, war

I have a web application - deployed on Tomcat.

It has two modules
Module A and Module B

Both have java code as well as UI component (struts\JSP etc.)

Functionally, Module A is independent an doesn't depend upon Module B
For ModuleA:
We create a war for Module A and deploy it as ModuleA.war

Now Module B depends upon Module A
We so "merge" the two modules into ModuleB.war
This involves merging the web content directories into one

We were feeling uncomfortable with this whole process of merging and wondering if there is a smart way to do this ?
We are also considering putting all the web content in one of teh modules - say Module A
and just keep the java code in ModuleB

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the java problems.
Say you app A is the public website, say your app B is your admin, but uses same database, same bizlogic classes,etc.
I found this problem all time. My approach might help you.

module A will have classes related only to project A
module B will have classes related only to project B
mod A and B will share a .jar file who contains all related classes, you can deploy it in TOMCAT/lib or if you want maintain it individually, deploy it in each app  MYAPP/WEB-INF/lib